# Почему функция min в Python отрабатывает неправильно?

Tags: python, lambda, лямбда-выражение

Нужно получить минимальное значение из tuple за исключением нулей. Написал вот такую функцию:

```
print(min(values, key=lambda x: x or max(values)))
```

если values=(1, 0, 1, 0), печатает 1, всё правильно, но если values = (0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), печатает 0. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так происходит потому, что у нуля ***вес*** получается таким же, как и у единицы:

```py
values = (0, 1)

print(0 or max(values))  # 1
print(1 or max(values))  # 1
```

А [функция](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) возвращает ***первое*** найденное минимальное значение. Поэтому если 0 идёт раньше, чем 1, то он и возвращается:

> The key argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that
> used for list.sort().
>
> If multiple items are minimal, the function returns the first one
> encountered.

---

Я бы на Вашем месте отфильтровал значения, например так:

```py
values = (0, 1)
result = min(x for x in values if x != 0)  # 1
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо огромное, час голову ломал! Впредь буду всегда читать официальную документацию, вместо быстрых гайдов из поиска

Answer (score 1):

зачем так сложно?

```
res = min(filter(lambda x: x != 0, values))
```